# How do I perform the following SQL sum?

Tags: sql

Suppose we have the following table

```
match_id, user_id, score

1000, 1, 359
1000, 52, 290
1001, 1, 429
1001, 59, 374
```

Basically in match_id 1000, user_id 1 wins 359-290, in match_id 1001, user_id 1 wins 429-374

To work out the total points user 1 is easy

```
select user_id,sum(score) as pointsfor group by user_id
```

How do I determine how many points were scored against?  Basically what should X in the following SQL be?

```
select user_id,sum(score) as pointsfor,sum(X) as pointsagainst  group by user_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test right now, but try something like:

```
SELECT
  PointsFor.user_id, 
  sum(PointsFor.score) as pointsfor,
  sum(PointsAgainst.score) as pointsAgainst
FROM TABLE_NAME PointsFor
JOIN TABLE_NAME PointsAgainst
  on PointsFor.match_id = PointsAgainst.match_id
  and PointsFor.user_id <> PointsAgainst.user_id
GROUP BY PointsFor.user_id
```

Obs: Replace `TABLE_NAME` above with the actual name of your table.

Comment: How does this query differentiate between wins and losses?

Comment: @mrcrowl It doesn't. The wanted data is how many points were scored for and against, not the win-lose count.

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a try

```
select user_id, sum(score) as pointsfor,
    (select sum(score) 
      from tab b 
      where a.match_id=b.match_id and a.user_id !=b.user_id) as pointsagainst 
from tab a
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know whether the score is for or against is to compare the scores.

I'd use a subquery to first determine the points, and then sum up per user: (this assumes your table name is "Points"):

```
select user_id, SUM(pointsfor) as PointsFor, SUM(pointsagainst) as PointsAgainst, SUM(pointstied) as PointsTied
from (
    select a.user_id, case when a.score > b.score then a.score else 0 end as PointsFor,
    case when a.score < b.score then a.score else 0 end as PointsAgainst,
    case when a.score = b.score then a.score else 0 end as PointsTied
    from points a
    join Points b on a.match_id = b.match_id and a.user_id != b.user_id
) sub
group by sub.user_id
```